# Removing Parent Nodes without affecting child nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

The XML output i am getting is not in the format that i require so tried some code to change the format but was unable to

This is the output that i am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
<Header>
<MessageId>{A124-B421-C325-D467}</MessageId>
<Action>find</Action> 
</Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
      <Run xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run">

        <RunObject class="entity">
          <A1>NA</A1>
          <A2>False</A2>
          <A3>02</A3>
          <A4>ER</A4>
        </RunObject>

        <RunObject class="entity">
          <A1>NA</A1>
          <A2>False</A2>
          <A3>03</A3>
          <A4>ER</A4>
        </RunObject>

      </Run>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

This is the XML output that i require

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>

      <Item>
        <A3>NA</A3>
        <A4>False</A4>
        <A2>02</A2>
        <A1>ER</A1>
      </Item>

      <Item>
        <A3>NA</A3>
        <A4>False</A4>
        <A2>03</A2>
        <A1>ER</A1>
      </Item>

</Document>
```

This is the code that i have used to change the format of the xml that i was getting

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run"
exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:Envelope"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:Header"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageId"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:Action"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:Body"/>

  <!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
    <Document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Run/*"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- rename RunObject to Item + reorder child nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <Item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A3" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A4" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A2" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A1" />
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried the above code but was not able to change the format of the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 <xsl:template match="m:Envelope"/>
```

that removes the `Envelope` node **and all its descendants**, you need to remove only the `Envelope` wrapper and continue processing its contents:

```
<xsl:template match="m:Envelope">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Likewise for the other wrappers. In fact, you could replace all of these:

```
  <xsl:template match="m:Envelope"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:Header"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageId"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:Action"/>
  <xsl:template match="m:Body"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:template match="m:*">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Was able to remove the Envelope, Header, MessageId,Action and Body tag but the value inside MessageId tag and Action tag are still present

Comment: Was able to get the desired format after making the changes but can you please explain why were the values still present although the tag was removed

Comment: Because `xsl:apply-templates` applies templates to **all** child nodes, including text nodes - and the built-in template for handling text copies it to the output.